# get and set with UserDefaults not saving string

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to store the userId locally in NSUserDefault, however when I try and set it and try to print it it return nothing, how come is that?

first I initialize `UserDefaults`

```
fileprivate static let userDefaults = UserDefaults()
```

then I set the userId string

```
public static var userId: String {
    get {
        return userDefaults.string(forKey: "userId") ?? ""
    }
    set {
        userDefaults.set(userId, forKey: "userId")
    }
}
```

then I set it and print it

```
    Globals.userId = "5876ad241aa7e973b1f8ec5b"
    print(Globals.userId)
```

Comment: Try changing `userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In setter, `newValue` variable keeps newly assigned value. So you should implement like below:

```
set {
        userDefaults.set(newValue, forKey: "userId")
}
```